# Create client credentials flow with custom policies from Azure

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, clientcredential

I would like to know how I could create a client credentials flow with custom policies. any example???

thanks

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

- You won't be able to claim customization with Azure AD client credential flow. We need to release azure AD B2C client credential flow, which leads claims customization using a custom policy, similar as authorization code flow.
- For complete information regarding Claim Process, you can go through this [Microsoft Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow).